# Directive-Controller communication issues with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive that has an `ng-repeat` inside the template of the directive.  I want the data from the `ng-repeat` to come from the controller in which the directive is nested. The ng-repeat is not running...

**Directive template**

```
<div class="taskList" ng-repeat="task in taskList | orderBy : dueDate">
  <div class="taskTopLine"></div>
  <div ng-class="taskCircleClass" ng-style="changeCircle" 
       ng-click="completeTask(task); fillCircle(task)">
  </div>
  <div class="task-check" ng-show="showCheck"></div>
  <p class="taskSubject" ng-click="goToTask(task); editTask(task)">
    {{ task.name }}
  </p>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
const taskItem = ($state, DataService, $rootScope, $uibModal, $window, $ngConfirm, inform) => {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: './app/views/directives/taskItem.directive.html',
    scope: {
      taskList: "="
    },
    link(scope, element, attrs) {
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.taskList = [];    
DataService.getTasks().then(data => {
   const temp = _.filter(data, o => { return moment(o.dueDate).isAfter(begin) && moment(o.dueDate).isBefore(end); });
   $scope.client;
   $scope.taskList = temp;
   $scope.taskList.forEach((row, index) => {
        row.sequence = index;
   });
});
```

Comment: What is the issue? Describe the problem.

Comment: `<directivename task-list='taskList'/>`?

Comment: provide a plunkr link, if you can. your question is not descriptive enough.

Comment: Good thought Slava, i tried that one too, no dice.

Comment: Can you include the html where you are calling the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue turned out to be with the `ng-hide`, not the `ng-repeat`